# Как настроить правила переноса для форматтера black?

Tags: python, black

Пытаюсь настроить black в рамках pre-commit-hooks таким образом, чтобы он форматировал код в едином стиле. Кодовая база достаточно большая, написанная в определенной стилистике, под которую и пытаюсь подогнать конфигурацию black - тут и произошли затруднения. Самая распространенная и популярная проблема black - это двойные или одинарные кавычки, решение которого уже давно существует. А вот как правильно настроить правило переноса строки - решения не нашел.

Легче показать именно на примере для наглядности.
Используется `sqlalchemy` для запросов. Пример абстрактный.

```
def get_user_sample_by_id(db:Session,_id:int):
    return 
         (
          db.query(User.id). 
          filter(name='Anthony')
          .one()
         ) # Вариант отработки black-formatter
    # вариант который нужно получить настроив black. 
    return db.query(
              User.id).filter(
              name='Anthony').one()
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей?